# default is not a constructor when using own Typescript typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm declaring a module in typescript:

```js
declare module 'myweb' {
  export default class MyWeb {
    constructor(url: string);
  }
}
```

When I import it by `import MyWeb from 'myweb';` I get error `TypeError: myweb_1.default is not a constructor`.

It gets transpiled to:

```js
const myweb_1 = require("myweb");
...
new myweb_1.default(url);
```

It seems right to me.

There are also other exported elements in module so I can't use `export =`

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The javascript itself is a library I can't change, but the code is:

```js
var MyWeb = function MyWeb() {
    var _this = this;
   processParams(this, arguments);
}

module.exports = MyWeb;
```

Comment: If you also have an implementation, could you please post the implementation of `myweb` too. That would help us find the type declaration to match it.

Comment: Hi, pls see the *edit* in the question above. Thanks

Comment: The JavaScript library that you showed does not export anything. That could be the problem. You said there "are other exported elements in module." Can you please show where, if at all, the module does an export of `MyWeb`.

Comment: You are right, I was missing it here, I have added it to the last line. The javascript library is exporting `module.exports = MyWeb`

Comment: Since it is using `module.exports = MyWeb`, the module is exporting one and only one element. What makes you think there are other exported elements in the module?

Comment: But other exports are in typescript, not in js

Comment: It is important, because it seems impossible for there to be another export in the same file (`myweb.js`) when the module is exporting the class with `module.exports = MyWeb`. Doing that would overwrite any other exports in that file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209030/discussion-between-o-o-and-shaun-luttin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the run-time error, here is a start for you from the [official documentation on modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) about how to handle `export =`.

> When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` must be used to import the module.

As a result, your `import` needs to be this:

```
import MyWeb = require('myweb');
```

Regarding the type definitions, it is hard to provide guidance without seeing more about the module's structure. For instance, what do you mean when you say, "There are also other exported elements in module..."?